# delay in transaction

Tags: bitcoin-core

I created an account with bc-wallet.com, and they gave me this wallet address 3HxxDmCWgLu2yJfrbTjdhfPTqEW7aftX3b and I sent to to a friend of mine who uses block chain account, and asked him to transfer bitcoins to me, he did it and up to now nothing has show up in my account... I'm very confused if this is my address or the address is a spam.... Please help me with this..... since yesterday around 19:00 GMT..

Comment: what message gets your friend does the transaction is confirmed?

Comment: Multiple transactions have been made to this address: https://blockexplorer.com/address/3HxxDmCWgLu2yJfrbTjdhfPTqEW7aftX3b.  There are even a few transactions from this address that appear to pay change back to the address.  The transactions start back in May.  I don't know if this is the sort of activity you would be expecting on the address, but that's what the blockchain tells us.

Answer (score 1):

The [address](https://blockexplorer.com/address/3HxxDmCWgLu2yJfrbTjdhfPTqEW7aftX3b) you've linked has been involved in eleven transactions already. If you don't see anything in your account, either it is not your address, or the website is not working correctly.

Looking at the website of bc-wallet.com, it looks hastily made to me. Are you sure that it is a proper wallet service and not a phishing/scam site?